# Data becoming a proxy when trying to make a SearchBar with vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

i have an application made with VueJs3, and i trying to make a searchbar based on `.filter()`, and it seems to be working, but when i try to pass te value from my methods to my template its making a huge error, my data is becoming a proxy, and i cant use the data in a proxy format.

The code:

```
<template>
  <div class="searchBar">
    <input type="search" v-on:change="filterList" />
    {{ search }}
  </div>
  <div id="listaDestaque" class="list">
    <div class="list-header">
      <p>Imagem</p>
      <p>Descrição</p>
      <p>Categoria</p>
      <p>Un</p>
      <p>Estoque</p>
      <p>Valor</p>
    </div>
    <div v-for="item in current_data">
      <div class="item-list">
        <img v-bind:src="item.attributes.image" class="item-image" />
        <p>{{ item.attributes.name }}</p>
        <p>{{ item.attributes['category-name'].name }}</p>
        <p>{{ item.attributes['unit-name'].name }}</p>
        <p>{{ item.attributes['quantity-in-stock'] }}</p>
        <p>{{ item.attributes.price }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import api from '../../services/axios.js';
import headers from '../../services/headers.js';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'listaDestaque',
  data() {
    return { myList: [], search: '', filter: '', current_data: '' };
  },
  beforeMount() {
    api.get('/products/all', headers).then((response) => {
      this.myList = response.data.data;
      const filter = this.myList.filter((element) => element.attributes.highlight == true);
      this.current_data = filter;
    });
  },
  methods: {
    filterList() {
      this.$data.search = event.target.value;
      console.log(this.search);

      const myListArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.myList));

      const filtered = myListArray.find(
        (element) => element.attributes.name == this.search
      );

      const filteredArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(filtered));

      if (filtered) {
        this.current_data = filteredArray;
        console.log(this.current_data);
        console.log(filteredArray);
      }
    },
  },
});
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

The code refering to the search bar is between the lines 2-5 and 35-65.

The `console.log(filteredArray);` in line 64 return this:

```
Proxy {id: '1', type: 'products', attributes: {…}, relationships: {…}}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Object
attributes: {name: 'Small Marble Chair', description: 'Nihil est dignissimos. Quia officia velit. Est aliquid eos.', quantity-in-stock: 12, price: 58.21, highlight: true, …}
id: "1"
relationships: {category: {…}, unit: {…}}
type: "products"
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

And i recieve the error in lines 17-22 after i user the function filterList:

```
listaDestaque.vue:17 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image')
    at listaDestaque.vue:17:42
    at renderList (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2905:26)
    at Proxy._sfc_render (listaDestaque.vue:24:11)
    at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:896:44)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5651:34)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:185:25)
    at instance.update (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5694:56)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:155:36)
    at flushJobs (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:396:17)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that a value changes to a proxy should not be causing any issues.

The issue is that you are using `const filtered = myListArray.find(...)`. The result of `find` is either a null or the first object in the array that matches your criteria, so `filteredArray` will never have an array as the content. When you pass it to the template though, you use `for in` so the iterator will go through your objects' properties (ie `item` at some point will be `attributes`, so `attributes.attributes` will be unefined, ergo `attributes.attributes.image` throws an error.

You probably meant to use `filter` instead of `find`

```
  const filtered = myListArray.filter(
    (element) => element.attributes.name == this.search
  );
```

---

I think the solution is a bit overcomplicated here

you can use `v-model` for the search input and the filtered dataset can use a `computed`

example:  ([SFC](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNqdVUtu2zAQvcqAKCAJsKV8UCBRbQNt2l0LdFF0EwUFLdExU4lUyFFaw9FpuuhBcrEOJVmW8mnTLGxzPpw38/hIb9nbsgxvKsFiNkNRlDlHsUgUwCyTN5Dm3Np5wqzgJl2/4yZhTZDCUpUVAm5K0ccTBjfTQmciH7iibsN2C60L6rqpHxFAi4R8mQuQGe3KpUX+XtDXdSWo3q4B599j41rwrDOcafp1E1xQgdTIu993v/QsInscPaMRL7WR/JHYB4uakB+JfOW5NiM/GTtg59+3NMOlzjbD/oiXlTY0hySOQSpIK2OEwm8ZR97P1SZnC6LK5YUc0chlhcKGiheCiCOc/dxPJZ97aTvhZuq2eRfP33hdcYUSN1OppsRE+v35m8PSyPRBj2OOelpo7c6c1rTaq45Md3AlQs7VJdGFtiNHFqU2CFvIxEoqcabJVkQg1LAyugCPJOy9cZnuk2plERy3ViDM4byT4L7beOuoiRPGyzInoU0gYSPWEkbBlakkyc4FHzBDCXAQHk2gmTumlFfH4elJwup68jRcSVfgpWgjrMN/Y2lDJL54tuP/nEx+XtOJPIWmNNJB/R3x8GQEeXoSHp32oBdOHQDiZ6MDUgGv8uZ3qAZ/2/bXtATe6DHxut6dKvwAukwAI7AyipRVbD5SfgznF5PupaISXt2ICmA3+lLQRRafdEVogypRBLyUUNAoIts5SXxfZCF0hb4fzBd9coK4ljZsAUmeO6E22m3B4PXBQXAPOqUxifIs3sMOnxE/6N39VAOccCVzFMb3RS4K2hPAfAHd+v5LE0qV5lUmrN8UaNkIAri9JXa6rqivYXu163YWtdd3wSasvbHTgpfhldWK/l+a9kgoTYAudj9Hwuj2Ojtha8TSxlFkV6n7V7qyoTaXEa1CQ4wTmaGwxXRp9A8rDBVOWAOeqJrVfwDCKDNh))

```html
<template>
  <div class="searchBar">
    <input type="search" v-model="search"/>
    {{ search }}
  </div>
  <table id="listaDestaque" class="list">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Descrição</th>
        <th>Categoria</th>
        <th>Estoque</th>
        <th>Valor</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="item in current_data">
        <td>{{ item.attributes.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.attributes['category-name'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.attributes['quantity-in-stock'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.attributes.price }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
  
  const dataset = [
    {attributes:{name:"apple", "category-name":"fruit", "quantity-in-stock": 0.2, price: "$3.98"}},
    {attributes:{name:"pear", "category-name":"fruit", "quantity-in-stock": 2, price: "$1.98"}},
    {attributes:{name:"orange", "category-name":"fruit", "quantity-in-stock": 3, price: "$3.98"}},
    {attributes:{name:"iPhone", "category-name":"not fruit", "quantity-in-stock": 18, price: "$398.29"}},
  ]

  export default defineComponent({
    name: 'listaDestaque',
    data() {
      return { myList: [], search: ''};
    },
    beforeMount() {
      // api mocked
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.myList = dataset  
      }, 500);
    },
    computed: {
      current_data(){
        return this.myList.filter((element) => element.attributes.name.includes(this.search)) || [];
      }
    },
  });
</script>
```